# Adding table with flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

In my basic web application, when click to "calculate" button there can be two options.
First, there is only one result so I directly show them to the users.
Secondly, there can be more than one result so I need to use table to show my results.

For the first option, I can show my result like below:

```
<p>Result {{result}}</p>
```

But I cannot figure out if my "result" parameter is array and how can I show all values of array in the table in my html file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over your iterable in your template:

Python script:

```
users = [{"name": "123", "hash": "qwe"},]

@app.route('/index/')
def index_page():
    return render_template('index.html', users=users)
```

Template:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><span>Hash - Name</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
    <tr>
      <td>
       <span>{{user['hash']}} - {{user['name']}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

See [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/) for more details about iterating over a loop in jinja2 templater.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your `result` to render in python script:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', result='yes')
```

And in tempalte:

```
<p>Result {{ result }}</p>
```

In browser:

```
<p>Result yes</p>
```